# How to use visual studio to apply DB migration using dbMySql provider instead of dbFullSql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I want to deploy an ASP.NET application to a remote server which is using MySQL.

In Visual Studio, When deploying using Web Deploy, there is no setting to specify which Web Deploy Provider to use and so from Debug log, it is saying this:

Adding database (server=localhost;database=DB;user=aaa;persistsecurityinfo=True)
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): Warning : **Cannot connect to the database 'DB'**.
Retrying operation 'Add' on object **dbFullSql** (server=localhost;database=DB;user=AAA;persistsecurityinfo=True). Attempt 1 of 10.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): Warning : **The database 'DB' could not be created**.

I know that for MySQL, I need to use `dbMySql` provider instead of `dbFullSql`, but how do I specify it on Visual Studio?

Note: using .NET 6 in windows

Comment: If you want to use MySQL in Visual Studio, you can refer to this link: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-connection-server-explorer.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-connection-server-explorer.html).

Comment: @samwu Sorry, that is not what I want, I want to let Web Deploy to execute the migration to MySQL during application publishing

Comment: Web Deploy enables you to package your web application content, databases, It can't change this during deployment, you can try to change it in vs, and then use web deploy to publish the application.

Comment: @samwu Yes, currently I am using VS to execute update-database and then deploy, but I see that Web Deploy support using many different provider such as `dbMySql` provider for MySQL, but the default is always `dbFullSql` (for MS SQL), so I guess there must be a setting to specify that, otherwise this is useless for other type of DBs